# Is there a way to loop through GPIO pins and a database in python

Tags: gpio, python, mysql, pygame

I have built a set of musical stairs using raspberry pi, motion sensors and python, and a web app to change the instrument using PHP. The python connects to a mysql database storing the instrument types. The issue is just that I feel there is bound to be a way to reduce the code and as I am very new to python I was just wondering how could I go about it.

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb # connect to mysql
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO # GPIO
import pygame.mixer # To make sound

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # GPIO set mode
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#Motion sensor setup
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True: 
  #Connect to database
  mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='*****', password='*****', database='*****')
  cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM settings WHERE active = 'true'")

  for id in cursor:
    print("ID: {}").format(id)
    print type(id[0])

    input_state = GPIO.input(4)
    print("input 4 {}").format(input_state == False)
    if input_state == False:
      if(id[0]==1):
        print "GPIO4 Piano"
        C1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("piano/C1.wav")
        C1.play()

      if(id[0]==2):
          print "GPIO4 Drum"
          drum1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("drum/Drumc1.wav")
          drum1.play()

      if(id[0]==3):
          print "GPIO4 Mute"
          C1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("piano/C1.wav")
          C1.stop()

    input_state = GPIO.input(17)
    print("input 17 {}").format(input_state == False)
    if input_state == False:
        if(id[0]==1):
            print "GPIO17 Piano"
            D = pygame.mixer.Sound("piano/D.wav")
            D.play()

        if(id[0]==2):
            print "GPIO17 Drum"
            drum2 = pygame.mixer.Sound("drum/Drumd.wav")
            drum2.play()

        if(id[0]==3):
            print "GPI017 Mute"
            D = pygame.mixer.Sound("piano/D.wav")
            D.stop()

    input_state = GPIO.input(27)
    print("input 27 {}").format(input_state == False)
    if input_state == False:
        if(id[0]==1):
            print "GPIO27 Piano"
            E = pygame.mixer.Sound("piano/E.wav")
            E.play()

        if(id[0]==2):
            print "GPIO27 Drum"
            drum3 = pygame.mixer.Sound("drum/Drume.wav")
            drum3.play()

        if(id[0]==3):
            print "GPIO27 Mute"
            E = pygame.mixer.Sound("piano/C1.wav")
            E.stop()

    input_state = GPIO.input(22)
    print("input 22 {}").format(input_state == False)
    if input_state == False:   
        if(id[0]==1):
            print "GPIO22 Piano"
            F = pygame.mixer.Sound("piano/F.wav")
            F.play()

        if(id[0]==2):
            print "GPIO22 Drum"
            drum4 = pygame.mixer.Sound("drum/Drumf.wav")
            drum4.play()

        if(id[0]==3):
            print "GPIO22 Mute"
            F = pygame.mixer.Sound("piano/C1.wav")
            F.stop()

    input_state = GPIO.input(23)
    print("input 23 {}").format(input_state == False)
    if input_state == False:   
        if(id[0]==1):
            print "GPIO23 Piano"
            G = pygame.mixer.Sound("piano/G.wav")
            G.play()

        if(id[0]==2):
            print "GPIO23 Drum"
            drum5 = pygame.mixer.Sound("drum/Drumg.wav")
            drum5.play()

        if(id[0]==3):
            print "GPIO22 Mute"
            G = pygame.mixer.Sound("piano/C1.wav")
            G.stop()
```

Comment: Probably you want to use callbacks (aka. event handlers) to deal with the GPIOs instead of a loop.  Also note that questions about how to use an SQL database in python are more appropriate to our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), as the brand of hardware is not particularly relevant.

Comment: Does the code do what you want it to do?  If so kudos to you as that is impressive for someone starting out in programming.

Comment: So far it's working fine - it crashes every now and then but for the most part it does what I want it to do. I'm just aware it looks very repetitive and I'm not sure how to go about changing that without affecting how it works

Comment: notice that `while True:` is used, not `while True == True:` .... the `if` statements are the same way ... use `if not input_state:` instead of `if input_state == False:`

Comment: @KatieArmstrong There are ways of tidying the code but I'm not sure I would bother as I think you'd end up with "tidier" code but I think it would be less clear.  Software has artistic aspects just like architecture.  It's personal choice and personal style.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @jsotola !